# SQL Server query: An invalid datetime value was encountered. Value exceeds the year 9999

Tags: sql-server, datetime

When I run this query:

```
select TimeUtc, CompanyId from dbo.storedcommands
```

SSMS will start pulling down the first 3,8 million records out of 4,1 million before it finally gives me this message:

```
An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

The strange thing is that the column datatype is datetime so I don't get how reading it can cause an overflow unless some data got corrupted.

[image: Table defintion]

Now my question is, how can I find out why this is happening and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE:** Neither CheckDB or CHECKTABLE with Data_Purity checks report anything. But there seems to be some data corruption on the index at least.

[image]

Comment: How did you get the data into the table? Have you tried DBCC CHECKTABLE to check for corruption?

Comment: @AndreasVendel No error messages from running: 

DBCC CHECKTABLE(StoredCommands);

Is there any other options that might be useful?

Comment: Data has been inserted through INSERT statements. But this is actually a backup of the production DB created through .bacpac

Comment: your id is bignint ,but your error talks about datetime

Comment: how about using try_Cast to find offending row

Comment: @TheGameiswar Yes, but if you look at the filter for that query those rows should be there. Seems like something is off

Comment: can you script out table defintions along with statistics for us to test

Comment: if the table is small, you also can provide total data by pasting it in gist github or script stats(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics)

Comment: 3930606 = `000000000000000000000000000001110111111100111101110` and `1125899910773230` = `100000000000000000000000000001110111111100111101110` so one bit has been flipped. Possibly in memory if checkdb didn't find anything and rebooting resolved it.

Comment: Nice catch @MartinSmith. Didn't think of checking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that things looked corrupted I decided to reboot the computer. Guess what. Now it's working again...

Reasons I even tried a reboot:

- I was pretty sure it worked earlier and I hadn't inserted any new
  rows
- No data_purity checks gave any errors
- Googling this errors gives many hits. But only for updates/inserts/casts/additions. Never for queries. Error noone else
  have deserves a reboot before spending time on.
- The results I got from the query above seemed super weird and should not be possible as we are far from that Id seed.

Comment: Aaaah, ye olde ["Have you tried turning it off and on again"](https://youtu.be/5UT8RkSmN4k) :-)

Comment: What did you reboot? The client machine or the server? Or are these both the same?

Comment: @MartinSmith It was on a dev box so it was the same.

Comment: @MikaelEliasson probably worth running a memtest utility against that box.